# Entity framework : The state value of a new object

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm using vb.net and entity framework.
I add a new object (Myobject) and before the savechanges is called , I try to modify it.
After that I check the context.entry(Myobject).state and the result is EntityState.Modified.
But this is a new record . Why the state isn't Entitystate.Added ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitystate(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **Added:**    The object is new, has been added to the object context, and the SaveChanges method has not been called. After the changes are saved, the object state changes to Unchanged. Objects in the Added state do not have original values in the ObjectStateEntry.

You can use the `EntityState.Added` like this

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blog = new Blog { Name = "ADO.NET Blog" }; 
    context.Entry(blog).State = EntityState.Added; 
    context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

Comment: I want to find and use the context.entry(Myobject).state after these 2 instruction : 1) Add the object 2) modify it  . The changes are not yet saved( no Savechanges is called). After these 2 instruciotn I check the state value and is Entitystate.modified. But I thing it should be EntityState.Added. ( because I have added the new object, but is not saved yet and is modified before the this new object is saved).